# Angular JS: Show the Input value as Selected in Dropdown

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-options, angularjs-select

I am newbie to Angular JS. I did find for the solution, but didn't resolved it.

As per selected value in dropdown, value should be displayed in corresponding Input box.

For Eg: If Basic is selected, corresponding value i.e 299 should be displayed in ng-model item.rate
If Advanced is selected, Corresponding value i.e. 499 should be displayed in ng-model item.rate.

HTML:

```
<tbody>
 <tr ng-repeat="item in invoice.items ">
 <td><select  ng-model="item.names" ng-options="c.name for c in invoice.items track by c.id"></select></td>
<td><input type="text" ng-model="item.rate"/></td>
</tr>
 </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Angular JS:

```
$scope.invoice = {
            items: [{id:1,name:'Basic',rate:299},
                    {id:2,name:'Advanced',rate:499}
               ]};
```

My Code is not working.I am unable to find out the Problem.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a typo. It should be `item.name` not `item.names`.

Comment: @anuragasaurus I do tried that, but it shows [object] object in Dropdown

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ngOptions` full syntax `value as text for item in items` to bind the options with `item.rate`, see [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

```
ng-options="c.rate as c.name for c in invoice.items track"
```

Also I recommend you to avoid binding `item.name` to `select` and binding an extra filed to avoid conflicts.

refer below example.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.selectedItem = '';
    $scope.invoice = {
      items: [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'Basic',
          rate: 299
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Advanced',
          rate: 499
        }
      ]
    };
    $scope.show = function(item) {
      return item.name + '(' + item.rate + ')';
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="c.rate as c.name for c in invoice.items"></select></td>
  <td><input type="text" ng-model="selectedItem" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but, Selected value should be displayed too like Basic and Advanced in dropdown.

Comment: @sam007 so you want to show both `name` and `rate` in textbox? check the updated example.

Comment: Not Like that..Displayed in Dropdown box itself.

Comment: @sam007 sorry, I didn't mention that(example fixed).  do you have duplicates in your array since you are using `track by`?